# Why can't my android webview load JavaScript

Tags: android, webview

I want to load a login page with JavaScript but I couldn't get the JavaScript to load even though i made a setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

```
    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);



        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        webView.loadUrl("https://itsikkerhed.talentlms.com/index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable DomStorage: `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`